# Parse String with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyVuS/1/)

I have got a simple select menu containing all countries with their city's listed in respective option value.
The value also contains some other data, for instance `Canada` has value `+1|}|22|X` while `United States` has this `+1|}|128|X||{|58$Abilene#|{|59$Akron#|{|1$Alabama#|{|2$Alaska#|{|60$Albany#|....`

I need to fill another select menu on change of country select menu.
I can't figure out how can i parse each city listed in the country's value.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any string manipulation methods, you'll have to use javascript methods to do it.

Comment: start by looking where you might get same data in simpler format

Comment: @charlietfl ..   `;/`  .. looking for some country-city database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this, idk, that data was kind of weird:

```
$('#country_residence').on('change', function () {
    var cities = $(this).val().split('$');
    $("#cities option").remove();
    for(var i = 1;i<cities.length;i++)
    {
     var city = String(cities[i]);
        if(city.indexOf("#")>-1)
            city = city.substring(0,city.indexOf("#"));


        $("#cities").append("<option>" + city + "</option>");
    }
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EyVuS/3/

Answer (score 0):

*If* there was absolutely no other way to get cleaner data? I'd do some (albeit somewhat brain-melting) regular expression matching on the server side to filter the information and then parse it into a usable list for use with JSON.

I, for one, would not attempt to do this on the client side.